# When should tf.losses.add_loss() be used in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I cannot find an answer to this question in the TensorFlow documentation. I once read that one should add losses from `tf.nn` functions but it isn't necessary for functions from `tf.losses`. Therefore:

When should I use `tf.losses.add_loss()`?

Example:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_corss_entropy_with_logits
                       (labels=ground_truth, logits=predictions))

tf.losses.add_loss(loss) <-- when is this required?
```

Thank yoou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One would use this method to register the loss defined by user.

Namely, if you have created a tensor that defines your loss, for example as `my_loss = tf.mean(output)` you can use this method to add it to loss collection. You might want to do that if you are not tracking all your losses manually. For example if you are using a method like `tf.losses.get_total_loss()`.

Inside `tf.losses.add_loss` is very much straightforward:

```
def add_loss(loss, loss_collection=ops.GraphKeys.LOSSES):
  if loss_collection and not context.executing_eagerly():
    ops.add_to_collection(loss_collection, loss)
```

Comment: thank you. Perhaps you could explain whether functions from tf.nn need to be added to the losses collection or not and edit your answer accordingly. This seems still confusing to me and others.

Comment: Whatever loss is created through any sort of standard library would already be added to LOSSES collection. therefore the is no reason to use add_loss() on them. If you write a loss function yourself - this is a good candidate for this method

Comment: hi, @y.selivonchyk, thanks for your answer, I'm very new to TensorFlow, what do you mean by "You might want to do that if you are not tracking all your losses manually"?